# sessionfactory creation takes a lot of time to load for the first time

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

I am working on a maven application development using hibernate.

While loading up the application for the first time the session factory takes a lot of time to load (around 3-4 minutes), but the subsequent session factory creation happens instantaneously. Can someone help me to figure out what changes I should make to reduce the time lag?

Here is the hibernate utility file:

```
package com.infosys.common.util;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

/*import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;*/

// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
/**
* The Class HibernateUtilities.
*/
public class HibernateUtilities {

    /** The Constant CONFIGURATION_LOCATION. */
    private static final String CONFIGURATION_LOCATION = "com/infosys/common/util/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtilities.class.getName());

    /** The session factory. */
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    /** The service registry. */
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    /**
     * Gets the session factory.
     *
     * @return the session factory
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the session factory.
     *
     * @return the session factory
     * @throws Exception
     *             the exception
     */
    public synchronized static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("Logger Name: " + LOGGER.getName());

                // Step1 : Loading the configuration details from
                // hibernate.cfg.xml

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(CONFIGURATION_LOCATION);
                configuration.
           setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults","false");

                // Step2 : Creating ServiceRegistry using the
                // StandardServiceRegistryBuilder and Configuration defined in
                // Step 1
                serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure(CONFIGURATION_LOCATION).build();

                // Step3 : Creating the SessionFactory using the Configuration
                // and serviceRegistry.
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Close session factory.
     */
    public static void closeSessionFactory()
    {
        if(sessionFactory!=null)
        {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite normal.
The first time you configure hibernate and use session factory (i.e. when you run the program), it needs to read your hibernate config, all your POJO files & your map files, make sure that your map, POJO and database match etc.
So the first run always takes time

Comment: i have seen other program using the same hibernate method which takes very less time. is there any changes i can do in my code??

Comment: Is the database in your local network? Maybe a bad network connection causes the delayed startup?!

Comment: my team is using MySQL workbench in our company network